# How do I return a result based on criteria versus totals given?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a sheet that looks similar to this:

[image]

So column A and column B are combined along with a number in column C. What I am trying to do is add up each value in each column (for example: add each C column for each time "Cat" appears, and "Dog" and "Grass", etc) and then find the value in columns A and B that is the highest, and return that value.

So for example, in my example above, Dog would be the formula result because it's C column totals to 28. Is there a formula (or, most likely, a combination of formulas) that can accomplish this?

Also, is it possible to do the inverse: so it would show the least combined value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for max:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A:A, C:C; B:B, C:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by sum(Col2) desc 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0), 1, 1)
```

for min:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A:A, C:C; B:B, C:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by sum(Col2) asc 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0), 1, 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver!